# Using SetOnCompletelistener in Soundpool instead of Mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I'm creating an app using android studio, and to manipulate my sound files, I was using `Mediaplayer`, but this class has some lag (when setting loops) and take a lot of memory , so I tried to use `Soundpool` which was really a great change.

All I need is a method like `SetOnCompletelistener` in `Soundpool`, i know this method doesn't exist , i tried a lot of solution like creating a new class which use both `Soundpool` and `Mediaplayer` but nothing really works fine.

Any help will be appreciated, ty all.